# Film and TV terminology tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

It seems we have a couple of different tags which are different ways of saying "film and tv terminology":

- [movie-jargon](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie-jargon)
- [terminology](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology)

There are also many other questions which would fit in this category but have no similar tags, such as:

- [What is the term called for the sudden blackout before the suspense scene?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/14482/what-is-the-term-called-for-the-sudden-blackout-before-the-suspense-scene)
- [What is the movie term for only seeing what is on camera?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/21868/what-is-the-movie-term-for-only-seeing-what-is-on-camera)
- [A term for a animation style used in anime](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/23352/a-term-for-a-animation-style-used-in-anime)
- [When an actor is supposedly but not actually looking at someone or something](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17633/when-an-actor-is-supposedly-but-not-actually-looking-at-someone-or-something)

[And many more](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=term%20is%3Aquestion%20-[terminology]%20-[movie-jargon]%20-[identify-this-movie]%20-[plot-explanation]).

I'm certain we should merge [movie-jargon](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie-jargon) and [terminology](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology), but what about the others? And what should the merged tag be called?

Answer (score 3):

As it's my personal preference and I really don't like the term "jargon":

**Put them all under the [terminology](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) tag**.

It's short and to the point, and doesn't make a distinction between film and television, which there really doesn't need to be.

Comment: After two months it seems the community has unanimously accepted your proposed solution as the best one. Now we only need a moderator to do the dirty work.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Ask and you shall receive?

Comment: I agree with this as well (though I think we shouldn't confuse 'support' with 'unanimous support'--I don't think you *can* get unanimous support on SE sites. :)